# Prove that if $n$ is an integer and $n^3+1$ is odd, then $n$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Prove that if $n$ is an integer and $n^3+1$ is odd, then $n$ is even.

Proof: Suppose $n$ is an even integer and $n^3+1$ is an odd integer. Then $n=2k$. $n=(2k+1)^3+ 1$, so $2k +(2k+1)^3 + 1= 8k^3+12k^2+8k+1 = 4(2k^3+3k^2+2k+1)$.

I am not sure if how I am starting the converse proof is correct, and if it is correct, I am a little stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: You need to prove that if $n$ is odd then $n^3+1$ is even.

Comment: $n^3+1$ is odd implies $n^3$ is even which implies $n$ is even (for rigor, use contradiction: suppose $n$ is odd, then $n^3$ must be odd, a contradiction).

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Suppose $n$ is odd. $n=2k+1$. Then $n^3$ is odd (*why?*). So...

You need to show that $n$ is even. So you can't start with $n$ even. You need to start with "$n$ is *not* even" (which is same as $n$ is odd) and arrive at a contradiction.